# Spring Boot @Scheduled cron

Tags: spring, cron, spring-boot, schedule

Is there a way to call a getter (or even a variable) from a propertyClass in Spring's `@Scheduled` `cron` configuration? The following doesn't compile:

`@Scheduled(cron = propertyClass.getCronProperty())` or `@Scheduled(cron = variable)`

I would like to avoid grabbing the property directly:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.scheduling}")
```

Comment: what about creating a bean that gets that value, then autowiring the bean into your cron class?

Comment: Is propertyClass a bean, or just class that contains static methods?

Comment: @bmoc That question addresses a different problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer - it's not possible out of the box.

The value passed as the "cron expression" in the `@Scheduled` annotation is processed in `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` class using an instance of the `StringValueResolver` interface.

`StringValueResolver` has 3 implementations out of the box - for `Placeholder` (e.g. ${}), for `Embedded` values and for `Static` Strings - none of which can achieve what you're looking for.

If you have to avoid at all costs using the properties placeholder in the annotation, get rid of the annotation and construct everything programmatically. You can register tasks using `ScheduledTaskRegistrar`, which is what the `@Scheduled` annotation actually does.

I will suggest to use whatever is the simplest solution that works and passes the tests.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to retrieve the cron expression from a property file you can do it programatically as it follows:

```
// Constructor
public YourClass(){
   Properties props = System.getProperties();
   props.put("cron.scheduling", "0 30 9 * * ?");
}
```

That allows you to use your code whitout any changes:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.scheduling}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CronProperties {

    private String expression;

    public String getExpression() {
        // Logic to dynamically determine the cron expression
        return "0 0 0 * * *";
    }

    public void setExpression(String expression) {
        this.expression = expression;
    }
}

@Autowired
private CronProperties cronProperties;

@Scheduled(cron = "#{cronProperties.expression}")
public void runTaskWithDynamicCronExpression() {
    // Your task logic here
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
@Component
public class MyReminder {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${my.cron.expression}")
    public void excecute(){
        someService.someMethod();
    }
}
```

in /src/main/resources/application.properties

```
my.cron.expression = 0 30 9 * * ?
```

Comment: That is my current code. My question is about using a variable or a getter instead of `${my.cron.expression}`