# spring @scheduled cron with variable

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

in our system we use a settings class to point to the properties file, depends on which eve it loads different property file. To access specific property, we call 'Settings.getString('property_name_here')'.

In my code, i loaded the @scheduled cron expression to a variable and try to passed to the @scheduled annotation, but it won't work,

here is my code:
in properties file:

```
cron.second=0
cron.min=1
cron.hour=14
```

in constructor i have:

```
this.cronExpression = new StringBuilder()
            .append(settings.getString("cron.second"))
            .append(" ")
            .append(settings.getString("cron.min"))
            .append(" ")
            .append(settings.getString("cron.hour"))
            .append(" ")
            .append("*").append(" ").append("*").append(" ").append("*")
            .toString();
```

which create a String of "0 1 14 * * *", it's a valid con expression

in the scheduled task i have:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${this.cronExpression}")
public void scheduleTask() throws Exception {
         ....
 }
```

when I ran the code it complaint:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'scheduleTask': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 1 in "${this.cronExpression}")

then I changed this.cronExpression to a list of String:

```
    this.cronExpression = Lists.newArrayList();
    this.cronExpression.add(settings.getString("cron.second"));
    this.cronExpression.add(settings.getString("cron.min"));
    this.cronExpression.add(settings.getString("cron.hour"));
    this.cronExpression.add("*");
    this.cronExpression.add("*");
    this.cronExpression.add("*");
```

but still got the same error, so what exactly is the cron expression supposed to be?

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204858/spring-boot-scheduled-cron). I don't think what you are trying to achieve is supported (use a variable in this place). Maybe you can have in a property the complete cronExpression, and use it, if that is an option for you.

Comment: thanks, it explained everything

Comment: Can you please also post the solution that you implemented in the end ? How did you managed to use the cron from a variable ?

Answer (score 11):

What I did and it worked for me:

In properties file:

```
my.cron.expression=0 3 * * * ?
```

In code:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${my.cron.expression}")
public void scheduleTask(){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi,
The solution you posted works as a static cron and not essentially picked from a variable. It's just replacing the hardcoded value by reference in the property file.
I

Comment: Yes, you are right. That was what I needed at the moment. And what I was looking for when I found this question ;)